# AWS Cognito UserPool - Recovery Option

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cognito, aws-userpools

I do see the RecoveryOption listed here
https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cognito-userpool-recoveryoption.html

But the in UserPool, I don't see RecoveryOption
https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-cognito-userpool.html

Anyone used RecoveryOption already with Cloudformation.

Please advice if this is an documentation issue or any limitation around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RecoveryOptions is part of RecoveryMechanism which is part of AccountRecoverySetting:

```
{
  "RecoveryMechanisms" : [ RecoveryOption, ... ]
}
```

Here you are an example of an user pool with recovery options, put all together in your CloudFormation template like this:

```
  testUserPool:
    DependsOn: [ cognitoSMSRole ]
    Type: AWS::Cognito::UserPool
    Properties:
      AccountRecoverySetting:
        RecoveryMechanisms: 
          - Name: verified_email
            Priority: 1
          - Name: verified_phone_number
            Priority: 2
      AdminCreateUserConfig: 
          AllowAdminCreateUserOnly: False
      AutoVerifiedAttributes: 
        - phone_number
      EnabledMfas: 
        - SMS_MFA
      MfaConfiguration: OPTIONAL
      Policies: 
        PasswordPolicy: 
          MinimumLength: 8
          RequireLowercase: True
          RequireNumbers: True
          RequireSymbols: True
          RequireUppercase: True
          TemporaryPasswordValidityDays: 7
      Schema: 
        - AttributeDataType: String
          DeveloperOnlyAttribute: False
          Mutable: False
          Name: name
          Required: True
        - AttributeDataType: String
          DeveloperOnlyAttribute: False
          Mutable: False
          Name: last_name
          Required: False
      SmsConfiguration:
          ExternalId: !Sub cognito-sms-role-prod
          SnsCallerArn: !GetAtt cognitoSMSRole.Arn
      UsernameAttributes: 
        - phone_number
      UsernameConfiguration: 
        CaseSensitive: False
      UserPoolName: !Sub UserPool-prod
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the RecoveryOption already. It is in AccountRecoverySetting
https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-cognito-userpool.html#cfn-cognito-userpool-accountrecoverysetting